# Mui throws when creating custom theme

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui

I want to create a custom style using Mui's `createTheme` function, but it throws an error:

```
/home/karol/Dokumenty/dev/katalog/node_modules/@mui/material/styles/createTheme.js:1
import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.@mui/material/styles/createTheme (/home/karol/Dokumenty/dev/katalog/.next/server/pages/_app.js:92:18)
error - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
/home/karol/Dokumenty/dev/katalog/node_modules/@mui/material/styles/createTheme.js:1
import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.@mui/material/styles/createTheme (/home/karol/Dokumenty/dev/katalog/.next/server/pages/_app.js:92:18)
```

themes/baseTheme.ts:

```js
import createTheme from '@mui/material/styles/createTheme';

export default createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#212121',
            light: '#484848',
            dark: '#000000',
            contrastText: '#ffffff',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#0d7377',
            light: '#4ca2a6',
            dark: '#00474b',
            contrastText: '#ffffff',
        },
    },
});
```

pages/_app.tsx:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import baseTheme from '../themes/base';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={baseTheme}>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Worth to note, when I run the app without `ThemeProvider` and then add it in so hot reload is triggered, everything works fine and the styles are applied correctly. It throws after next reload.

Comment: Hi! Did you happen to find the issue? Have been banging my head over this for a while :(

Comment: This is probably a typescript bug, for me a workaround was to use named import - `import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';`

Comment: Yes, I ended up discovering the same thing after a while. Thanks for the help